# Team Problem solving

Tags: combinatorics

If I am having a lawn party with games and I have 10 different couples and each couple brings a lawn game.
How do I set it up that each couple plays each other once and plays a different lawn game?
Is it possible?

Comment: Hmm.. if I may ask.. how are you stuck on this?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to show us what your schedule might look like if there were just two couples at your lawn party. What about three couples?

Comment: The bridge players call it a Mitchell movement.

Comment: @RossMillikan It's not so trivial. The typical problem you think of is making pairings. But here you need to make triplets, so that each time a different game is played

Comment: @AleksejsFomins:  the games correspond to the boards in a bridge tournament.  The Mitchell movement takes care of that.

Comment: I wanted every team to play the other 9 teams and a different lawn game.